# Joomla - Uncaught exception, Error 500 - less block

Tags: joomla, less

I've migrated a Joomla site to a new server, updated the configuration.php file, and I'm getting these errors:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Less Parse Error: parse error: unclosed block' in
/var/www/websites/alwaysevolving/libraries/gantry/core/gantry.class.php:1141 Stack trace: #0
/var/www/websites/alwaysevolving/templates/rt_cerulean/features/styledeclaration.php(45): Gantry->addLess('mediaqueries.le...') #1
/var/www/websites/alwaysevolving/libraries/gantry/core/gantry.class.php(415): GantryFeatureStyleDeclaration->init() #2
/var/www/websites/alwaysevolving/libraries/gantry/gantry.php(289): Gantry->initTemplate() #3
/var/www/websites/alwaysevolving/libraries/gantry/gantry.php(439): gantry_template_initialize() #4
/var/www/websites/alwaysevolving/templates/rt_cerulean/lib/gantry/gantry.php(21): include('/var/www/websit...') #5
/var/www/websites/alwaysevolving/templates/rt_cerulean/index.php(15): require_once('/var/www/websit...') #6
/var/www/websites/alwaysevolving/libraries/joomla/document/html/html.php(531): require('/var/www/websit...') #7
/var/www/websites/alwaysevolving/libraries/joomla/do in /var/www/websites/alwaysevolving/libraries/gantry/core/gantry.class.php on line 1141
```

It looks like there's a problem parsing one of the less files, but:

1. **I can't tell which one of the less files has the issue**
2. **The less files were fine on the other server**
3. **The site seems fine, so it seems like something in this template doesn't like my new server.**

Thoughts??

Thanks!

Comment: Wow, super giant boldness! My bad!

Comment: Error 500, isn't there something wrong with `rewrite module` such as `.htaccess` inside ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is a stack trace, but looking at it, it appears that the Gantry framework parsing the `less` file called `mediaqueries.less`.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly believe that you have forgetten to close braces }. make sure to check the line number will help you resolve the issue.